# How do I access the highlighted text in a Matlab GUI edit box

Tags: matlab, matlab-gui

I would like to have a text box and a button in my GUI. When the button is pressed, a history window will come up, and if the user selects a previous entry the text that they have highlighted in the edit box will be overwritten.

It should work like copy-pasting, whatever is selected in the history window should be pasted over what is selected, or the new text should be added wherever the cursor is.

Is there any way in Matlab to do this? Is it possible to access what is highlighted in an edit box?

Answer (score 1):

With vanilla Matlab this isn't possible. It appear that Mathworks is in the process of expanding what they support with GUIs ([survey 1](https://mathworks.getfeedback.com/r/n7Uo2uCK/), [survey 2](https://mathworks.getfeedback.com/r/s7CMT9fY/)), but as of yet they don't allow this.

One possible workaround is using [findjobj.m, by Yair Altman](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects). He discusses edit boxes [in this post](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-editboxes)

You can trace findjobj.m for your text box to find 1 or 2 lines of code that are needed so you don't have to carry around all 3,400 lines of it.

Then all you really need to do is get the selected indices and work from there.

```
javaHandle  = findjobj(editBoxHandle);
startSelect = get(javaHandle,'SelectionStart');
endSelect   = get(javaHandle,'SelectionEnd');
```

Once you have the indexes of what text is selected, it becomes almost trivial to replace that text with the new text.

```
text = editBoxHandle.String;
editBoxHandle.String = [text(1:startSelect) newText text(endSelect:end)];
```

One thing to note, when the user clicks the button the text box will lose focus, and it will no longer be clear what text is selected. You can remedy this by giving focus back to the text box, and re-selecting what was selected in the button's callback.

```
uicontrol(editBoxHandle); %Give focus to the edit box, selecting the entire text
javaHandle.select(startSelect,endSelect); %select/highlight the correct stuff
```

This will highlight the text that will be replaced with the users selection